# Not able to get account information with MEXC API

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

I am trying to use the following code to grab my account information from MEXC.

```
const { clear } = require('console')
const Mexc = require('./dist/js/package')
const client = new Mexc.Spot()
client.config.apiKey = "xxxxx"
client.config.apiSecret = "xxxx"

const prices = client.accountInfo()
console.log(prices)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error message, please help:

```
E:\Tradingbot\mexc-api-sdk\dist\js\package\node_modules\http-response-object\lib\index.js:51
            throw err;
            ^

Error: Server responded to https://api.mexc.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1710186033600&signature=dbe50886c46db2a9dd5ba8788ae1be7b353bc0d972bd8f6919f973523ac24a97 with status code 400:
{"code":700002,"msg":"Signature for this request is not valid."}
    at ...
```